# jQuery body onChange with multiple elements and multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I limit the execution of multiple body onChange-functions to truly only run if the selector grabs?

```
$('body').on('change',$selectRadios,function(e){
    // do something and stuff like
    $btnNext.removeAttr('disabled');
    console.log('I should only run if I change $setupRadios')
}

$('body').on('change',$selectCheckboxes,function(e){
    // do something else and stuff without interfering with the first onChange-function like
    $btnNext.attr('disabled',true);
    console.log('I should not run if I change $setupRadios');
}
```

If I do that, if I change $selectRadios the btnNext will not be re-enabled, but it will stay disabled (it actually runs the second function as I can see in the console as it logs the «I should not run if I change $setupRadio» too)

**Update:** I have to use event delegation from body instead of direct cached elements because of $selectRadio and $selectCheckboxes are dynamically added to the page with some more scripts

**Update 2:** The $selectRadio and $selectcheckboxes are being added via something like:

```
function addTeam() {

for(var i = 0; i < resultSetupCount; i++) {

    $('.js-setup ul').append($('<li tabindex="0"><input class="js-setupRadio" type="radio" id="setup'+(i+1)+'" name="setup" value="setup'+(i+1)+'" data-setup0="'+resultSetupGoalie[i]+'" data-setup1="'+resultSetupAbwehr[i]+'" data-setup2="'+resultSetupVorne[]+'" data-trck="setup-'+resultSetupTrck+'-clicked" tabindex="-1" /><label for="setup'+(i+1)+'"><img alt="" src="'+resultSetupImg[i]+'" srcset="'+resultSetupImg[i]+' 1x, '+resultSetupImg2x[i]+' 2x" /><span>'+resultSetupName[i]+'</span></label></li>'));

}

}
```

-> see .js-setupRadio

Comment: You are using Event delegation, then why are you using cached element?

Comment: @Satpal: so I can't use any cached elements for this?

Comment: `onchange` is for form elements, I don't recall it being for body.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sort out what was actually changed during an event, use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). You should be able to replace the alert with your functions and it should work only as the clicked element as context.

### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {
      var $inputs = $('input');
      $('#set').on('change', $inputs, function(e) {
            var changed = e.target;
            $inputs.each(function(index, element) {
              var ele = this.className;
                  if (this == changed) {
                    alert(ele+index+' has changed');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="set">
  <input class="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input class="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input class="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input class="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad1">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad1">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad1">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad2">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad2">
  <input class="rad" type="radio" name="rad2">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by testing if e.target is having the class from $selectRadios OR $selectCheckboxes and only run the content of the functions if true:

```
$(document).on('change',$setupRadios,function(e){

    var $that = $(e.target);

    if ($that.hasClass('js-setupRadio')){
        // do something and stuff like
        $btnNext.removeAttr('disabled');
        console.log('I should only run if I change $setupRadios')
    }

});

$('body').on('change',$selectCheckboxes,function(e){

    var $that = $(e.target);

    if ($that.hasClass('js-checkbox')){
        // do something else and stuff without interfering with the first onChange-function like
        $btnNext.attr('disabled',true);
        console.log('I should not run if I change $setupRadios');
    }

});
```